# "Unfortunately (app name) has stopped" in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-animation

I am developing an android app using eclipse. Every time I run it in the AVD I get the error "Unfortunately  Has Stopped". Im trying to transition between the Startup activity and the Main Menu activity using android animation.
Here is part of my java code to support the main activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_up);
    startAnimating();
}
private void startAnimating() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1);
    TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondTV);
    Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.fade_in2);
    logo2.startAnimation(fade2);

    fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Startup.this, SymptomViewer.class));
            Startup.this.finish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });


    }
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    logo1.clearAnimation();
    TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondTV);
    logo2.clearAnimation();

}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    startAnimating();
}
}
```

I have been searching in forums all over the internet and I cant seem to solve the this. However I checked the logcat and I found something to do with Null pointer exception, which is involved when making references. I have run through my code a number of times and it seems fine. What maybe causing this.

**Here is the LogCat**

```
05-06 18:24:58.925: D/AndroidRuntime(1355): Shutting down VM
05-06 18:24:58.925: W/dalvikvm(1355): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a98ba8)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Process: com.example.ubumitrial1, PID: 1355
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ubumitrial1/com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup.startAnimating(Startup.java:27)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup.onCreate(Startup.java:17)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     ... 11 more
05-06 18:25:02.275: I/Process(1355): Sending signal. PID: 1355 SIG: 9
```

Comment: "I checked the logcat and I found something to do with Null pointer exception", ohhh you were so close! Post that logcat so we can tell you where that `NPE` is and why.

Comment: Best approach: show the actual logcat. Also: probably a textview that wasn't found or something

Comment: It has EVERYTHING to do with NullPointer... :/

Comment: Also, why are you calling `startAnimating();` in `onCreate()` **and** `onResume()`?

Comment: Also , post your layout

Comment: You say this is the code for your "main activity" but your `layout` is `start_up`. Did you use the wrong one?

Comment: codeMagic, thank you so much. I just posted the logcat. In a case where a the activity is interrupted, and so its paused it can get back to the foreground.

Comment: DigCamara, I have just posted the logcat

Comment: codeMagic, I used the wrong on when I posted this.

Comment: You need to go through your post and clean it up. You say it is main but you have start_up layout. Also, your `NPE` is at line 27 of `Startup`, what is there? Remove the `startAnimating();` from `onCreate()`. It will be called from `onResume()` when the `Activity` starts. No need to be in both places, otherwise it is called twice when the `Activity` first starts

Comment: codeMagic I'm cleaning it up just now, sorry. Line 27 of Startup has "ade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){". Thanks or the help, let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup.startAnimating(Startup.java:27)
```

These log lines show that the NPE happend at line 27. Go to that line (double-click the "at" line in Eclipse jumps to the code)

This will likely be a line like: `widget.doSomething()`. The NPE is thrown because `widget` is `null` (a previous initialization via `findViewById` may have failed, you have to fix the id in the layout [or code]).

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): Process: com.example.ubumitrial1, PID: 1355
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ubumitrial1/com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
```

As per this error message, I sense that You might not have declared this activity properly in your Manifest file. Did you define it correctly ? Please double check the declaration

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup.startAnimating(Startup.java:27)
05-06 18:24:58.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1355):     at com.example.ubumitrial1.Startup.onCreate(Startup.java:17)
```

As per this message you are referring to a component which is not  initialized properly. Please check you lines 17 and 27. Both of these should help to resolve your problem.

In case if unable to solve the problem, Feel free to post code with Line numbers highlighted and also your manifest file.

Comment: If it were a problem with the `Activity` not being declared in the `manifest` the error would be `ActivityNotFoundException` instead of `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Go to terminal type "android AVD" then wait till emulator start. Now go to eclipse run your android project and force project to run throw online emulator(that is still running).
Hope it works for you.
CHeers!